# Translating selection coordinates from a downscaled image

Tags: php, javascript, gd

I'm building a simple image cropping utility for a website.

I'm having a small problem: each time I do it there's distortion (my selection coordinates are roughly estimated so the image is drawn with wrong dimensions for example).

I sketched this to let you see what I mean:

[image]

Here's some code to help you get what I'm trying to achieve:

```
    //Get the new coordinates to crop the image.
    $x1 = $request->getPost('x1');
    $y1 = $request->getPost('y1');
    $x2 = $request->getPost('x2');
    $y2 = $request->getPost('y2');
    $w = $request->getPost('w');
    $h = $request->getPost('h');

    $croptool_width = $request->getPost('croptool_width');
    $croptool_height = $request->getPost('croptool_height');

    $original_width = $request->getPost('original_width');
    $original_height = $request->getPost('original_height');

    $infos = pathinfo($original_image_location);
    $extension = strtolower($infos['extension']);

    switch($extension) {
        case 'gif':
            $sourceImage = imagecreatefromgif($original_image_location);
            break;
        case 'jpg':
        case 'jpeg':
            $sourceImage = imagecreatefromjpeg($original_image_location);
            break;
        case 'png':
            $sourceImage = imagecreatefrompng($original_image_location);
            break;
    }

    // Take croptool's dimension, transpose selection coordinates to fit the original image.
    $scale_y = $original_height / $croptool_height;
    $scale_x = $original_width / $croptool_width;

    $scaled_x1 = $x1 * $scale_x;
    $scaled_y1 = $y1 * $scale_y;
    $scaled_x2 = $x2 * $scale_x;
    $scaled_y2 = $y2 * $scale_y;

    // Crop selection and save to disk
    $cropImage = imagecreatetruecolor(Model_Wineries::getCoverImageWidth(), Model_Wineries::getCoverImageHeight());

    imagecopyresampled(
        $cropImage, $sourceImage, 
        0, 0, 
        $scaled_x1, $scaled_y1,
        Model_Wineries::getLogoImageWidth(), Model_Wineries::getLogoImageHeight(), 
        $scaled_x2, $scaled_y2
    );

    if (file_exists($cover_image_location))
        unlink($cover_image_location);

    imagejpeg($cropImage, $cover_image_location, 90);

    chmod($cover_image_location, 0777);

    if (file_exists($original_image_location))
        unlink($original_image_location);
```

The part I'm having trouble figuring out is how to properly calculate the `$scale` variable.

$croptool_width and $croptool_height are both the downscaled dimensions. $original_... are the original ones.

Could anybody help me please?

EDIT: Suggested responses are good but for some reason anything done goes out totally wrong, please look here:

[image]

EDIT: (code has been updated)

Thanks!

Comment: Step back and let's ignore that code. What do you want to achieve, rather than what you already have. Does your script receive an image, and the crop coordinates/dimensions, and is then supposed to produce that crop? If so, consider using http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php to do the work for you.

Comment: Did you tried to change the aspect ratio? I have posted an anwser.

Comment: ImageMagick works by command-line, you can exec() or whatever from PHP or Java, it's incredibly well-tested & stable & widely supported.  You can also test the command-line calls & coordinates independent of your server, to get what you need.. I second @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans

Comment: there's also a PHP imagemagick API, so you don't need exec. Most of the functions are available straight from PHP

Answer (score 1):

May be i am missunderstanding, but i think you are calculating "proportion" not "scale". The scale is product of the original dimentions with the new ones. May be:

```
    $scale_y = $original_height / $croptool_height;
$scale_x = $original_width / $croptool_width;

$scaled_x1 = $x1 * $scale_x;
$scaled_y1 = $y1 * $scale_y;
$scaled_x2 = $x2 * $scale_x;
$scaled_y2 = $y2 * $scale_y;


//Original height = 1000 and Croptool height = 100 ==> scale_y = 10; Pixel (0, 45) on crop space == 45 * 10 == 450 on original image.
//Original height = 100 and Croptool height = 1000 ==> scale_y = 0.10; Pixel (0, 450) on crop space == 450 * 0.10 == 45 on original image.
```

Hope this helps.

EDIT:

I am not familiar with the PHP API, but it looks like the source width and source height provided are wrong, may be you can calculate as

```
 imagecopyresampled(
    $cropImage, $sourceImage, 
    0, 0, 
    $scaled_x1, $scaled_y1,
    Model_Wineries::getLogoImageWidth(), Model_Wineries::getLogoImageHeight(), 
    $scaled_x2 - $scaled_x1, $scaled_y2 - $scaled_y1
);
```

Comment: It's almost working but they're still a little distorted. For example if I select this: cl.ly/image/0L1Q1w441500 I get this result: cl.ly/image/0c1x3H0K0Z1k THANKS A LOT!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
original width * new height / original height = new width;

original height * new width / original width = new height;
```

[1] [Get aspect ratio from width and height of image (PHP or JS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8044052/get-aspect-ratio-from-width-and-height-of-image-php-or-js)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the whole solution but you've got a problem here:

```
imagecopyresampled(
        $cropImage, $sourceImage, 
        0, 0, 
        $scaled_x1, $scaled_y1,
        Model_Wineries::getLogoImageWidth(), Model_Wineries::getLogoImageHeight(), 
        $scaled_x2, $scaled_y2
    );
```

Per the php docs for this function, the last two parameters should be the source image width and height, but instead you're passing the coordinates. So instead of $scaled_x2, pass $scaled_x2-$scaled_x1, and instead of $scaled_y2, pass $scaled_y2-$scaled_y1