# Get image aspect ratio

Tags: php

I'm currently trying to get the aspect ratio of an image using PHP. For example, using those values :

```
$thumb_width = 912;
$thumb_height = 608;
```

I would be able to get the aspect ratio (16:9, 3:2, 2:3, etc.). So in this case :

```
$ratio = '3:2';
```

The thing is: I don't know what new width or height it will be. so I can't do something like that : `(original height / original width) x new width = new height`

Any ideas ?

*Note: I don't want to resize an image, just calculate its aspect ratio with its width and height.*

Comment: Won't this help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8044052/get-aspect-ratio-from-width-and-height-of-image-php-or-js?rq=1?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

So you need to get the size of an image

http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php

```
list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize("path/to/your/image.jpg");
```

so here you have `$width` and `$height` ready

Then you can use this answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/9143510/953684 to convert the result of `$width/$height` to a ratio.

Answer (score 4):

I always prefer the most compact solution in coding. They're mostly faster, more robust and better to read.

While [the option](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9143510/2593099%20will%20probably%20work) that is mentioned by [@Sharky](https://stackoverflow.com/users/953684/sharky) in the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36643018/2593099) will probably do the job, i think the following solution is much more elegant and definitely better readable:

```
$imageWidth = 912;
$imageHeight = 608;

$divisor = gmp_intval( gmp_gcd( $imageWidth, $imageHeight ) );
$aspectRatio = $imageWidth / $divisor . ':' . $imageHeight / $divisor;
```

More information about the functions in the PHP manual for [gmp_intval](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.gmp-intval.php) and [gmp_gcd](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.gmp-gcd.php).